# Typescript error accessing props.classes with material-ui and react-router-dom withStyles withRouter

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm struggling to get material-ui's theming to work with react-router-dom in Typescript. When accessing classes.root in `render()`, I get *TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined*, but I can't figure out how I'm merging/passing props incorrectly. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Relevant code below:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      maxWidth: 345,
    },
  });

interface HomeProps extends RouteComponentProps, WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  classes: any;
}

export class Home extends React.Component<HomeProps, HomeState> {
  constructor(props: HomeProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    //  classes.root is undefined...
  }
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Home));
```

Edit to add: the answer to this question did not resolve this issue: [Typescript error when using withRouter(withStyles(styles)(ComponentName))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604851/typescript-error-when-using-withrouterwithstylesstylescomponentname)

Answer (score 0):

There was some syntax errors in the code maybe it is the cause.
`WithStyles<typeof styles>` gives `this.props.classes` its type, you don't need nor should override it with `classes: any;`.

This works for me

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      maxWidth: 345,
    },
  });

interface HomeProps extends RouteComponentProps, WithStyles<typeof styles> {}

type HomeState = any;

export class Home extends React.Component<HomeProps, HomeState> {
  // constructor(props: HomeProps) {
  //   super(props);
  // }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <div className={classes.root}></div>
  }
}
```

[image: autocompletion completes `classes.root`]

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-kalam-u3mhx?file=/Home.tsx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this still results in the same error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a codesandbox? Because I don't see the error in mine.